# Counting how many times a string appears in a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, dataframe

I have a piece of code what is supposed to tell me how many times a word occurs in a CSV file. Note: the file is pretty large (2 years of text messages)
This is my code:

```
key_word1 = 'Exmple_word1'
key_word2 = 'Example_word2'
counter = 0
with open('PATH_TO_FILE.csv',encoding='UTF-8') as a:
for line in a:
    if (key_word1 or key_word2) in line:
        counter = counter + 1
print(counter)
```

There are two words because I did not know how to make it non-case sensitive.
To test it I used the find function in word on the whole file (using only one of the words as I was able to do a non-case sensitive search there) and I received more than double of what my code has calculated.

At first I did use the `value_counts()` function BUT I received different values for the same word (searching `Exmple_word1` appeared 32 and 56 times and 2 times and so on. I kind of got stuck there for a while but it got me thinking. I use two keyboards on my phone which I change regularly - could it be that the same words could actually be different and that would explain why I am getting these results?

Also, I pretty much checked all sources regarding this matter and I found different approaches that did not actually do what I want them to do. ( the `value_counts()` method for example)

If that is the case, how can I fix this?

Comment: Do your words have many letters with accents on?  Or non-ASCII characters?

Comment: The words have no accents. and no non-ASCII that I am aware of. the word is 'te iub'. Office word finds 3k+, my code finds around 1.5k. Maybe some of them could be non-ASCII and office can just count them? @MrB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice some mistakes in your code:

1. **key_word1 or key_word2** - it's "lazy", meaning if the left part -  "key_word1" evaluated to True, it won't even look at key_word2. The will cause checking only if key_word1 appeared in the line.

An example to emphesize:

```
w1 = 'word1'
w2 = 'word2' 
s = 'bla word2'
(w1 or w2) in s
>> False 
(w2 or w1) in s
>> True
```

2. **Reading csv file**: I recommend using csv package (just import it), something like:

```
import csv
with open('PATH_TO_FILE.csv') as f:
    for line in csv.reader(f):
         # do you logic here
```

3. **Case sensitivity** - don't work hard, you probably can lower case the line you read, just to not hold 2 words..

guess the solution you are looking for should look something like:

```
import csv
word_to_search = 'donald'
with open('PATH_TO_FILE.csv', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    for line in csv.reader(f):
         if any(word_to_search in l for l in map(str.lower, line)):
              counter += 1
```

Running on input:

```
bla,some other bla,donald rocks
make,who,great
again, donald is here, hura
```

will result:

```
counter=2
```

Comment: I am getting `_csv.Error: Unknown Dialect`

Comment: Sure you do, i accidentally left some unused and undeclared vars in the csv.reader func. Deleted it, try now

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.